# Convert table of oracle sql to mysql query table

Tags: mysql, oracle

How is it possible to convert the following oracle sql to a create table to mysql

```
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY' NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='english'; select sysdate from dual; 
    CREATE TABLE dept ( 
    value1 DATE not null, 
    value2 NUMBER(21,6) not null, 
    value3 NUMBER(21,6), 
    value4 references tem(temno));
```

Example of insert data:

```
insert into emp(value1,value2,value3,value4) values('02-APR-1989',26850,20,30);
```

Comment: You know that Your insert data are for table `emp` - > " Employee " . 
And You are asking about `dept` -> "Derpartment" . And its classic schema example from Oracle

Comment: @Take_Care_ yes thank you very much I changed it.

Comment: So as I see You just need to change 3 statements   `value2 INT not null, 
    value3 INT, FOREIGN KEY (value4)
        REFERENCES tem(temno)`

Comment: @Take_Care_ thank you. Is the date need any convert?

Comment: Probably ->  `STR_TO_DATE('2013-02-11', '%d-%b-%Y') ` and as 1st argument Your date-string. Or Just `DATE(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace Oracle's `NUMBER` datatype with MySql's `DECIMAL` datatype.
Your table definition references another table named `tem` here:

```
value4 references tem(temno)
```

this is so called *inline foreign key constraint*
You cannot create table `dept` if table `tem` has not been previously created, so the whole script in Oracle must look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tem(
  temno number primary key
);

INSERT INTO tem VALUES ( 1 );

CREATE TABLE dept ( 
    value1 DATE not null, 
    value2 number(21,6) not null, 
    value3 number(21,6), 
    value4 references tem(temno)
);

INSERT INTO dept VALUES( date '2017-01-22', 22.0, 13.5, 1 );
```

You have also to create table `tem` in MySql before creating the table `dept`

---

MySql doesn't support inline foreign key constraints, only out of line foreign key constrains work, so the tables definition in MySql must look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tem(
  temno decimal primary key
);

INSERT INTO tem VALUES ( 1 );

CREATE TABLE dept ( 
    value1 DATE not null, 
    value2 decimal(21,6) not null, 
    value3 decimal(21,6), 
    value4 decimal,
    constraint foreign key (value4) references tem(temno)
);

INSERT INTO dept VALUES( date '2017-01-22', 22.0, 13.5, 1 );
```

Live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/173b2/1

Note: a datatype of `value4 decimal` must be the same as a dataypepe of `temno decimal` in table `tem`, and also `tem(temno)` column must be a primary key,  otherwise you will get an error.